# What does 皆まで mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does 皆まで mean? As in 皆まで言うな

Don't say all of it?
Don't say it to everyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「[皆]{みな}**まで**言うな」 is a set phrase meaning "Don't finish what you're saying (because I already know)!"

「[皆]{みんな}**に**言うな。」 is a sentence, not a set phrase, that means "Don't tell everyone!"

「皆」 is pronounced differently in these two phrases.